# How does termios.h use bit masks to determine what mode the terminal should be?

Tags: c, input, terminal, output, bitmask

Basically, if I write:

```
struct termios raw;
tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &raw);
raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO);
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &raw);
```

so that the user input is not displayed, how does that one change in `c_lflag` allow `tcsetattr()` to work as intended?

Comment: Are you asking why setting the ECHO bit to 0 turns off echo?

Comment: @immibis Yes! Exaclty! I still don't  understand how it turns echo off.

Comment: You get the current settings, then you set echo to off in those settings, then you set the settings back on the terminal... I'm really not understanding what there is to not get.

Comment: The terminal driver (in the kernel) uses that information.  You'd have to read its source-code to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable ECHO to get the input NOT echo-ed on to the output, as follows:

```
toptions.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO);

if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &toptions) != 0)
{
    cout << "ERROR: " << errno << " from tcsetattr" <<endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

ECHO is defined as:

> **ECHO** in c_lflag controls whether input is immediately re-echoed as output. It is independent of ICANON, although they are often turned on
>   and off together. When passwd prompts for your password, your terminal
>   is in canonical mode, but ECHO is disabled.